# ExtendScript performance updating

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm currently writing a script for Illustrator, which uses ExtendScript, and was wondering if there were ways to multithread or other types of performance boosters in this language? For example, we draw a lot of shapes one after another, and I was unsure whether we could, for example:

- Draw multiple shapes at once.
- First calculate all shapes, then draw them, without constantly updating the Illustrator UI on every new shape, drawing the entire drawing at once, when "ready".
- Generating QR-codes in the background (as this is just a lot of number crunching), and once everything is generated, draw the code itself, whilst drawing other things as the QR-code is being generated in the background.

These are just some ideas off the top of my head, but am not sure whether these are even possible.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack overflow. If you have existing code and want to optimize it, you may want to post it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the question needs a lot work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - specifically, the code to be reviewed needs to be present in the question, and the title should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: In any case, if the performance isn't adequate and a full code review isn't wanted, then it would be appropriate here if it included enough reproducible code to be answerable.

Comment: I don't think a code review entry nor providing code is required. I'm merely asking whether it is possible to manipulate Adobe Illustrator's scripting behaviour within ExtendScript to improve performance, with some simple theoretical techniques as a brain dump.

Comment: The obvious answer would be: to froze the screen update, turn off redrawing the screen. But Illustrator, not like InDesign, doesn't have such option. There is the partial solution, to switch the screen into Outline mode (`app.executeMenuCommand('preview')`), and to hide the interface: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/suspend-ui-during-script-execution/td-p/11362997